# There are icon and label in one div, I want to change icon on click of label

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
 '<div class = "padding_Tables"><a href="#"><i id=collapseIcon class="fa fa-caret-down iconCollapse" " /></a><label class="tree-toggler nav-header collapsableLabel"> Overall </label>'</div>
```

I tried this script.

```
$('label.tree-toggler').click(function() {
    $('#collapseIcon').find('i').toggleClass('fa-caret-right fa-caret-down');
});
```

The icon and label are collapsible.

Comment: can you show me in jsfiddle?
You make two icon. one is hide and click on label you can show second icon and do first icon hide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to modify the class of `<i>` element, then change the below line,

`$('#collapseIcon').find('i').toggleClass('fa-caret-right fa-caret-down');`

to:

```
$('#collapseIcon').toggleClass('fa-caret-right fa-caret-down');
```

The `.find()` will search for descendents.

More info: [jquery .find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

Comment: I created a jsfiddle outlining just that before I was going to submit an answer... feel free to use it :) https://jsfiddle.net/ajpz9xg3/